# How can i access a nested json object ? | Displaying Orders in Laravel Ecommerce Project ]

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, object, laravel-7

```
{"**6732987ae9ac9ac3d465ea993bf9425c**": {"rowId":"6732987ae9ac9ac3d465ea993bf9425c","id":14,"name":"Stanley Metz","qty":2,"price":2039,"weight":550,"options":{"size":"large"},"discount":0,"tax":428.19,"subtotal":4078},"49b94e7c1fec3ef5540a81145e603955":{"rowId":"49b94e7c1fec3ef5540a81145e603955","id":3,"name":"Ms. Emmie Macejkovic","qty":1,"price":4478,"weight":550,"options":{"size":"large"},"discount":0,"tax":940.38,"subtotal":4478}}
```

as we can see this is a column of a row in my orders in the orders database,  so i need to access the nested object of the key **6732987ae9ac9ac3d465ea993bf9425c** in order to display the orders in the admin panel blade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have always only one key than you can simply;

```
$data = json_decode($jsonComesHere , true);
$data = array_values($data)[0];
print_r($data['name']); //or whatever you need
```

if you have multiple keys with objects

```
$datas = json_decode($jsonComesHere , true);
$datas = array_values($datas);
foreach($datas as $data){
 print_r($data['name']); //or whatever you need
}
```